# How to Provide two different cubits for the same page

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I Have two different cubits one for the Scan page [ScanCubit] it responsible for pick image from user
if image is null emit ScanFailure state  if image not null emit ScanSucces accompanied with the image
and the another cubit have varibleImage[image] and  method to upload the varibleImage [image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaseD.jpg)

```
    class DetectionCubit extends Cubit<DetectionState> {
  DetectionCubit() : super(DetectionInitial());
  File? image;

  sendDetectionData() async {
    emit(DetectionLoading());
    try {
      var list = await DetectionRepo.uploadImage(image);
      emit(DetectionSuccess(textResult: list.toString()));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
class ScanCubit extends Cubit<ScanState> {
  ScanCubit() : super(ScanInitial());

  final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  dynamic pickImageGallery() async {
    final XFile? imageXFile;
    imageXFile = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (imageXFile == null) {
      emit(ScanFailure(err: 'Empty Value'));
      return;
    }
    File? imageFile = File(imageXFile.path);
    emit(ScanSuccess(image: imageFile));
  }
}
```

This is The ui of the Scan Page  ,,, when scanSuccess state is emited take the accompanied image and try to access the the varibleImage[image] in the another cubit [DetectionCubit]
 [Scan Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNOfx.png)

```
class ScanViewBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScanViewBody({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenWidthSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenHeightSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return BlocConsumer<ScanCubit, ScanState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is ScanFailure) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('No Image Selected')));
        }
        if (state is ScanSuccess) {
          BlocProvider.of<DetectionCubit>(context).image = state.image;
          GoRouter.of(context).push(AppRouter.kDetectionResultView);
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ScanLoading) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        

        else {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomAppBar(
                    title: 'Detection',
                    onPressed: () {
                      GoRouter.of(context).pushReplacement(AppRouter.kHomeView);
                    }),
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenHeightSize * 0.1,
                ),
                Image.asset('assets/derm_-_hero_image_2_1 1 (1).png'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenHeightSize * 0.1,
                ),
                const Text('Detect your disease with only one click.... ',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                const Text.rich(
                  TextSpan(
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(text: 'Press'),
                      TextSpan(
                          text: ' Scan ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                      TextSpan(text: 'now on the Screen to Start Detection'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenWidthSize * 0.5,
                ),
                const CustomMaterialButton(text: 'Scan'),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt8uV.jpg)

i try to provide the two cubits for the scan page without using the MultiBlocProvider in the MaterialApp in the main ,,,,, because when i provide the DetectionCubit in the main the DetectionSuccess state doesn't change

Comment: more code is needed

Comment: can you specify what you need? and i will provide it to you

Comment: As per your code it is right because once you emit DeletionSuccessState after that no any new state is emit in DetectionCubit. So, no any new state you will get. If you want new state then after DetectionSuccess state emit new ResetState so you will get new state.

Comment: you are asking about provideng cubits, but don't provide code how exactly you are trying to provide them..

Comment: What if you wrap your BlocConsumer<ScanCubit> with a BlocProvider<DetectionCubit>?  And if the BlocProvider<DetectionCubit> is already defined somewhere  then try to wrap your BlocConsumer<ScanCubit> with BlocBuilder<DetectionCubit>.

Comment: AJJ - Thanks for your help , it worked